# scrapy spider is not starting start_requests function

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

Scrapy script stops abruptly after the spider is inititialised before the call of start_requests function.
I'm using Crawlrunner to initialise spider from a python script.

python script :

```
custom_settings = { 'ITEM_PIPELINES' : { 'url_crawl.pipelines.UrlCrawlPipeline': 300}, 'COOKIES_ENABLED' : 'True', }
runner = CrawlerRunner(custom_settings)

@defer.inlineCallbacks
def crwl():
    try:
        configure_logging({'LOG_FORMAT': '%(levelname)s: %(message)s'})
        lists = chunks(get_urls_to_crawl(), 30)
        for list in lists:
            print len(list)
            yield runner.crawl(UrlSpider, url_dict =list)
        d.addBoth(lambda _: reactor.stop()) #@UndefinedVariable
        reactor.run() #@UndefinedVariable
    except Exception as e:
        print e
```

and the spider looks like:

```
class UrlSpider(scrapy.Spider): 
    name = "url"  
    start_urls = [] 

    def __init__(self,url_dict):
        self.start_urls = []
        for url in url_dict:
            self.start_urls.append(url)

    def start_requests(self):
        user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.142 Safari/537.36'
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url = format(url[1]), headers={'User-Agent': user_agent,},callback=self.parse,meta = {'url':url[1],'id':url[0]})

    def parse(self, response):
        //////////////// extraction code //////////
```

the script stops abruptly after this log message:

```
2019-09-04 17:45:23 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
['url_crawl.pipelines.UrlCrawlPipeline']
2019-09-04 17:45:23 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2019-09-04 17:45:23 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2019-09-04 17:45:23 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
```

Comment: `yield scrapy.Request(url = format(url[1])...` if `url` is a string you'll just get the second character of the string...

Comment: `start_urls = []` you should configure some urls where the spider should start

Comment: @tomjn actually url is a list with the url string as the second item. sorry for the misleading naming.

Comment: @Casper even if the start_urls is empty the spider is supposed to call start_requests according to scrapy

Comment: Add some logging to `start_requests` to log `self.start_urls`. I would expect this to be empty.